# Player-Needs Tag Clarification

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

A recent question used the [player-needs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/player-needs) tag, and being unfamiliar with it I had a look at what other questions have used it. Having done so, I find that I have no clear idea as to what the tag is supposed to cover.

What is the correct use of the [player-needs](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/player-needs) tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Terminate with Extreme Prejudice**

It's only used on 14 questions, has no wiki description, and does not seem to be used consistently beyond questions that have something to do with players (but not problem players). It's amorphous and doesn't add anything to the questions it's used on.

[image]

Comment: Yes please, let's blow it up.

Comment: I recommend a proper user lynch mob. This doesn't need the ioncannon of the mods, and means that each question can get a bit of love.

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton All set.